# Insert record with form - CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, continuous-integration

I have an error after foreach. the message is Undefined variable: mapel

```
<?php 
            $no=1;
            foreach($mapel->result() as $row){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $no++;?>
                    <td><?php echo "".$row->$nm_mapel;?></td>
```

Comment: can u post the complete code where do you assign the query object to $mapel?

Comment: public function insert_mapel($data){
  $mapel=$this->db->insert("mapel",$data);
  return $mapel;
 }

Comment: You cannot iterate over an insert statement.It returns bool. what are you trying to achieve?